# ArcSDE In a version geodatabase, snap tool does not work on a database feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, snapping

I am setting up a series of tasks for technicians to complete. To finish the map template they will be working from, I must snap leak points to gas mains using the snap tool. However, after running the snap tool for 2 hours and getting a successful completion, the points are not snapped.

I have tested this using a copy of the leak points feature class without an ArcSDE version and the snap was successful.

Why won't the snap tool work on the ArcSDE version of the leak point feature class? This is being attempted from a in-map selection subset of the leak point file. Please note that the feature classes in this ArcSDE cannot be changed unless the version is changed.

To illustrate this problem, red dots below represent a successful snap run when performed as part of a model, green dots represent running the snap from ArcSDE from the stand alone snap tool. As you can see, the points did not snap.

[image]

Comment: Are you in an edit session when you try to run the Snap tool?  Is your data in a geometric network?

Comment: It was ran on the database class once in an edit session and once outside of an edit session. Both did not work. As far as I can tell, the data have not been turned into a geometric network. They are all database feature classes created using ArcSDE in 9.3. The snap tool wasn't added to the editing toolbox until 10 came out.

Comment: This question has been resolved. When working in a version geodatabase, the version must be closed or refreshed in order to reflect changes made to that version. For instance, when I started a new map document, loaded my leak points and gas mains, and changed the version to the one in which the snap tool was ran, the changes were reflected. I verified this by comparing my snap results from a model (proven to work) and the leak points in my version geodatabase. There are now no differences.